# using hash to change video src on a page

Tags: javascript, html, video, src

Changing the video source using a hash only works for one of the tags.

For example `mywebsite.com/video.php` will show the default video, and if I go to `mywebsite.com/video.php#video1` it will change to video-1 but if I go to `mywebsite.com/video.php#video2`, it still shows video 1.

```js
<script>
// test all possible places hash could be on different browsers
if(window.location.hash){
   hash = window.location.hash;
} else if (document.location.hash){
   hash = document.location.hash;
} else if (location.hash){
   hash = location.hash;
}

// some browsers start the hash with #, remove it for consistency
if(hash.substring(0,1) == '#'){
    hash = hash.substring(1,hash.length);
}

if(hash = '#video1'){
  document.getElementById('myVideo') .src=a = "http://mywebsite.com/videos/video-1.mp4";
}

if(hash = '#video2'){
  document.getElementById('myVideo') .src=a = "http://mywebsite.com/videos/video-2.mp4"";
}
</script>
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" controls>
     <source src="http://mywebsite.com/videos/video-default.mp4">
    </video>
```

How can i fix this? Is there a better way to change a src path using some sort of id?

Comment: You removed the `#` at the beginning of `hash`, then you included it in your `if` tests.

Comment: You're also using `=` when it should be `==` to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `=` when it should be `==`. And even though you removed the `#` at the beginning of `hash`, you still included it in the comparison strings.

```
if (hash == 'video1') {
  document.getElementById('myVideo') .src=a = "http://mywebsite.com/videos/video-1.mp4";
} else if (hash == 'video2') {
  document.getElementById('myVideo') .src=a = "http://mywebsite.com/videos/video-2.mp4"";
}
```